# didSelectViewController for subclass of UITabBarController not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitabbarcontroller

So I've created MainViewController which is a subclass of UITabBarController:

```
@interface MainViewController: UITabBarController {


}
```

I initialized this from the app delegate and then set delegate to self:

```
MainViewController * main = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
main.delegate = self
```

then I had:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{

}
```

but this was never called.. why is this? Is this because this was a subclass?

Comment: Did you found solution to the problem? I am having same issue

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify: do you have

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

in MainViewController, or in your app delegate?

That method should be defined in whichever class you choose to be your UITabBarControllerDelegate.  For example, in my app I have:

- A regular UITabBarController (there's no need to subclass UITabBarController unless you're doing something fancy)
- My app delegate implements UITabBarControllerDelegate - specifically, tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:
- I set tabBarController.delegate to be the app delegate

That should be everything you need.